# How to toggle a variable using React Testing Library for React function component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-functional-component

I am trying to write unit tests for a functional component which goes like this -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type Props = {
showPopup: boolean;
id?: string;
togglePopup: () => void;
reloadData: () => void;
};

const PopupComponent = ({
showPopup,
togglePopup,
reloadData = () => {}
}: Props) => {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

const onSuccess = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    //some logic
};
const onError = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    // shows error message
};
//Call to get users
getGroupUsers(
    groupId,
    onSuccess,
    onError
);
 
return (
   {isLoading ? (
                    <Row>
                        <Col noLeftGutter noTopGutter textAlign='center'>
                            <Spinner />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                ) : ( 
                    <Table data-testid='test-table'>// render table here with user data</Table> 
                    )
);
};
export default PopupComponent;
```

Here is the getGroupUsers implementation -

```
const getUsers = async (key: string, groupId: any) => {
    const response = await axios({
        url: userUrl({ roleGuid }),
        method: 'GET'
    });
    return response.data;
};

export const getGroupUsers = (
    groupId: any,
    onSuccess: FunctionSuccessError,
    onError: FunctionSuccessError
) => {
    return useQuery(
        ['management.getUsers', groupId],
        getUsers,
        {
            enabled: true,
            onSuccess,
            onError,
        }
    );
};
```

I wrote a unit test which checks whether Table is present or not. But I am not able to find a way to manipulate the isLoading to false. I tried Enzyme setState but that does not work with functional components.

I cannot bind the setIsLoading to any event such as onClick as there is no such functionality needed on the popup.

Here is the test I wrote -

```
it('it should check if table renders', async () => {
        const { findByTestId } = render(
            <PopupComponent showPopup={true}
                              togglePopup={togglePopup}
                              reloadData={reloadData}
            />
        );

        
           expect(await findByTestId('test-table')).toBeInTheDocument();
        
    });
```

This test gives me the following error as isLoading is true so it not getting rendered.

```
Error: expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has value: null
```

Does anybody know how to manipulate isLoading from the test ?

Comment: You don't, it's part of the internal state of the component. It looks to only be manipulated by `getGroupUsers`, but from what you've posted it's impossible to see where that's even coming from. Maybe it's an external service you could replace with a test double, maybe it's making a request you could use e.g. MSW to simulate, ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added the getGroupUsers implementation as well

Comment: Please give a coherent [mre].